# Как создать subset без определенного элемента?

Tags: r

Здравствуйте. Как создать subset без определенного элемента?
Например:

```
> a1<-c(1:5)
> a2<-c("bed","pillow","sleep","bed","pillow")
> a3<-c(6:10)
> df<-data.frame(a1,a2,a3)
> df
  a1     a2 a3
1  1    bed  6
2  2 pillow  7
3  3  sleep  8
4  4    bed  9
5  5 pillow 10
```

Мне хотелось бы получить subset  второго столбца, но без "pillow". Оператор NOT !, не работает. Как его здесь использовать правильно? Или может быть есть другие команды, позволяющие создать такой сабсет?

Comment: у меня вроде работает not: `subset(df, a2 != 'pillow')`

Comment: понял. благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Еще ( на мой взгляд) достаточно удобно делать subset  c помощью `[`(квадратных скобок).

Например `df[df$a2 != 'pillow',]`

Стоит обратить внимание ,что не рекомендуется использовать subset в определенных случаях

> Warning
>
> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For
>   programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like
>   [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset
>   can have unanticipated consequences

.

Результат тот же, но чуть быстрее чем обычный `subset`( на определенных наборах данных)

```
Unit: microseconds
                               expr    min      lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
 {     subset(df, a2 != "pillow") } 98.621 102.191 114.19937 104.4220 107.323 463.205   100
    {     df[df$a2 != "pillow", ] } 73.631  76.532  88.98195  78.0935  80.325 380.202   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю решение с помощью `dplyr`, поскольку этот пакет предоставляет, на мой взгляд, оптимальное сочетание удобства написания/прочтения кода и скорости исполнения.

---

Итак, решение выглядит следующим образом. Кстати, создавать данные можно сразу с помощью функции `data_frame()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(a1 = 1:5,
               a2 = c("bed","pillow","sleep","bed","pillow"),
               a3 = 6:10)

df_sub <- df %>% filter(! a2 == 'pillow')
```

---

#### Проверим скорость

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark( subset(df, a2 != "pillow"),
                df[df$a2 != 'pillow',],
                df %>% filter(! a2 == 'pillow'),
                filter(df, ! a2 == 'pillow')
)


Unit: microseconds
                           expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
     subset(df, a2 != "pillow")  61.009  73.9805  84.59654  80.3945  91.5130  168.200   100
        df[df$a2 != "pillow", ]  61.863  72.6970  88.89838  83.8160  96.0740  314.732   100
 df %>% filter(!a2 == "pillow") 310.456 339.1070 381.22235 364.0520 404.2485  579.290   100
    filter(df, !a2 == "pillow") 228.353 249.7340 300.94876 267.4090 314.1625 1601.882   100
```

Казалось бы, по скорости `dplyr` сильно проигрывает. Но это из-за очень малого размера датафрейма. Также обратите внимание, что очень удобный piping operator `%>%` замедляет исполнение кода.

Попробуем увеличить датасет в **тысячу** раз и сравнить скорость опять.

```
df2 <- data_frame(a1 = rep(1:5, 1e3),
                  a2 = rep(c("bed","pillow","sleep","bed","pillow"), 1e3),
                  a3 = rep(6:10, 1e3))


microbenchmark( subset(df2, a2 != "pillow"),
                df2[df2$a2 != 'pillow',],
                df2 %>% filter(! a2 == 'pillow'),
                filter(df2, ! a2 == 'pillow')
)

Unit: microseconds
                            expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
     subset(df2, a2 != "pillow") 128.858 140.9740 246.4695 146.9615 169.1980 1857.316   100
       df2[df2$a2 != "pillow", ] 115.459 126.2925 188.3296 137.2685 159.5045 1587.627   100
 df2 %>% filter(!a2 == "pillow") 343.525 358.3505 384.0674 376.1680 392.7025  578.149   100
    filter(df2, !a2 == "pillow") 265.128 278.3845 375.8885 293.3515 322.5720 3016.463   100
```

Все еще различия не в пользу `dplyr`. Попробуем увеличить исходный датасет в **миллион** раз и сравнить скорость опять.

```
df3 <- data_frame(a1 = rep(1:5, 1e6),
                  a2 = rep(c("bed","pillow","sleep","bed","pillow"), 1e6),
                  a3 = rep(6:10, 1e6))


microbenchmark( subset(df3, a2 != "pillow"),
                df3[df3$a2 != 'pillow',],
                df3 %>% filter(! a2 == 'pillow'),
                filter(df3, ! a2 == 'pillow')
)

Unit: milliseconds
                            expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
     subset(df3, a2 != "pillow") 129.24171 153.90437 193.8962 200.42959 214.1032 289.8579   100
       df3[df3$a2 != "pillow", ]  88.93557 106.71604 123.6339 112.33160 143.0285 197.5125   100
 df3 %>% filter(!a2 == "pillow")  73.45358  87.98082 103.9721  92.90250 107.3194 169.9390   100
    filter(df3, !a2 == "pillow")  73.26229  88.31038 106.6175  92.96208 108.6734 239.5112   100
```

И вот оно! На большом датасете `dplyr` быстрее.

Comment: У вас опечатка/ ошибка в `df[df3$a2 != 'pillow',]` , разные df .

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо! Редко я стал выходить за пределы `tidyverse`. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Кстати, дополнительно любопытное наблюдение: на миллионном датасете (`df3`) домашний i5 4GB Ubuntu 16.04 быстрее, чем рабочий i7 8GB win7!

Comment: а R и там и там 64 bit?

Comment: да, версия 3.3.2, не MRO

Comment: @Batanichek а вы не знаете набор более или менее стандарных команд для проверки скорости выполнения задач различного типа? Было бы интересно замерить.

Comment: Честно говоря , кроме `microbenchmark` ( для маленьких действий) и просто замера времени `Sys.time()` ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: @Batanichek не, я немного другое имею в виду. Технически, ничего лучше `microbenchmark` не требуется. Я имел в виду некий стандартный набор операций, который бы использовался для замера скорости. Типа Лены для алгоритмов сжатия изображений.